# [solved] Couldn't open Joystick /dev/input/js0

Tags: joystick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to "teleop" my turtlebot using a Logitech Attack 3 joystick. I bring up the turtlebot from a remote PC, followed by the command:

```
roslaunch turtlebot_teleop myjoystick.launch
```

where myjoystick.launch is the modified logitech.launch file with the added axis_deadman param. The terminal on my remote PC shows error `"Couldn't open Joystick /dev/input/js0. Will retry every second."` No response when joystick is connected to the remote PC. The turtlebot responds properly when I connect the joystick to the turtlebot netbook.

I tried changing permissions of /dev/input/js0 to 777 as well, with no help.

Also, keyboard teleop happens without any errors.

Why is the remote joystick teleop not happening and how do I fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218450/%5Bsolved%5D-couldn%27t-open-joystick-/dev/input/js0/) by [Loneflyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/24028/loneflyer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2015-09-30

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey , there is a document  about this problem , you can have a look.[here](http://wiki.ros.org/joy/Troubleshooting)

Maybe you haven't download `jstest`

---

Originally posted by [wsAndy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21662/wsandy/) with karma: 224 on 2015-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Loneflyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/24028/loneflyer/) on 2015-09-30**:
The joystick works fine when connected to the turtlebot netbook. It won't work in teleop from my remote PC.

I have tried all the troubleshooting steps from that documentation page, with no help.

**Comment by [wsAndy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21662/wsandy/) on 2015-10-01**:
Well, the maybe you should check your net.
Maybe you can try this way. First, link the joystick with your remote PC, in which if you can get the output , right? Then, you connect to turtlebot, and in its terminal you can get the output message or not.

**Comment by [wsAndy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21662/wsandy/) on 2015-10-01**:
If you cannot get the message, you need to set the `ROS_IP` in your `.bashrc` in both computer

**Comment by [Loneflyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/24028/loneflyer/) on 2015-10-01**:
The problem is solved actually. The problem was that I had not set ROS_IP on my remote machine, so a lot of applications that come later in the tutorials after teleop wouldn't open on my PC (like gmapping and rviz).

Thanks for all your help. I'm still a newbie and have a long way to go with ROS!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe your joystick is on another port, not js0.
you can test it with

```
ls /dev/input
```

plug and unplug your joystick and repeat the command, so you can see on which port (jsx) your joystick is detected.
Then change default port in the launchfile.

---

Originally posted by [fabian77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20410/fabian77/) with karma: 126 on 2015-09-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Loneflyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/24028/loneflyer/) on 2015-09-30**:
the ls command shows js0. Even jstest gives the required response with all the keys working.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Somewhat related to giving joystick access to the node is making sure that the device name is accurate.  My example happen when I was following the steps at: http://wiki.ros.org/joy/Tutorials/ConfiguringALinuxJoystick

For the following command in the step **01.Starting the Joy Node**

> $ rosparam set joy_node/dev
> "/dev/input/jsX"

Do not put quotes around the device name.

---

Originally posted by [ChaosBuster](https://answers.ros.org/users/36556/chaosbuster/) with karma: 11 on 2018-07-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1